# https request return 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND'

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, oauth-2.0

In my server web application after using Oauth2.0 i got a accessToken.Futher  i want to use the accesToken and get list of files in my google drive.

> GET /drive/v2/files HTTP/1.1
>   Authorization: Bearer access_token
>   Host: www.googleapis.com/

Here is my code

```js
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  'host': 'www.googleapis.com/',
  'path': '/drive/v2/files',
  'method': 'GET',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <access-token>'
  }
}
https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

But i'm getting

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.googleapis.com/

Comment: Very likely this is because the actual hostname does not end with a `/` character.

Comment: @apsillers  Nothing is getting console log.

Answer (score 0):

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  host: 'www.googleapis.com',
  path: '/drive/v2/files',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <access-token>'
  }
}
const req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log('Status Code:',res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:',res.headers);

    res.on('data',(d)=>{
        process.stdout.write(d);
    })
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
req.end();
```

reference link: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html